# How to use query string to find requesting page in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page signup.aspx where user can register, how this page will find from which page request came from and how it will redirect user after registration to the requesting page. I want to do this using query string but don't know how

Comment: PLZ SHOW ME CODES? Welcome to SO. You'll likely get better responses if you phrase your questions in a more professional manner. For reference, check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

On any links to the register page put

```
<a href="Signup.aspx?ReturnUrl=<%=Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>">Register Here</a>
```

then on your register form when they have registered add:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["ReturnUrl"]))
     Response.Redirect(Request["ReturnUrl"]);
else
     Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Hi, i did but it is giving this error " HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. "

Comment: probably need to urlencode the querystring url in the link (Request.Url.AbsolutePath).

Comment: i already did that like this HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]); But same error

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Request.QueryString["foo"] == "bar"){
    Response.Redirect("page.php", true);
}
```

This would get the information from http://www.example.com/registered.aspx?foo=bar

So Request.QueryString["QueryString"] is the value of anything after the ? and each variable after the &. so if you had http://www.example.com/registered.aspx?foo=bar&abc=def

Then you would have 2 querystrings, foo and abc.